# Android sdk files corrupted

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-sdk-2.3, android-api-levels

A little window popped up and said something like "do you wanna update Intent.java API 29 to 30", I said yes and all SDK files became like this. All of the imports and functions have a 'cannot resolve symbol ...' error. What i tried so far:

1. Removed Sdk's and downloaded it again.
2. Deleted cache, gradle, .idea files.
3. Deleted AVD (not related but who knows) and downloaded again.
4. Deleted Intent.java and compiled.
5. Clicked Invalid cache/restart.

None of them worked. I would love to hear your solutions.

Here is gradle:[image]
Here is corrupted file example:
[image]

Comment: please share the Gradle file

Comment: edited and shared

Answer (score 0):

only add animation dependency in build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

Comment: can you share code to Github or send code to my email? javaddehban1@gmail.com